# Is there a way to limit bandwidth for azureus?

Tags: bandwidth

I am downloading stuffs (legally) with azureus. And I want to play overwatch.

Can I do both?

Overwatch ping becomes insane.

Can I set azureus bandwith to low?

Comment: I don't know about Azureus but many other clients do have that option, either a toggle switch to a default capped download/upload and/or a value set by the user.

Comment: Router might be able to try, I think it's called QoS. Probably easier to just directly tell the program to slow down, most have limits available

Answer (score 0):

In Azureus Vuze go into menu *Tools > options*, click on *Transfer* and set the values of
"KB/s global max upload speed" and/or "KB/s global max download speed".

Set these to some values that will not slow down your bandwidth too much,
reset to zero when you don't need it any more.